# Sql_config failed error =21. this should never Occur

Tags: java, android, sqlite, motorola

I have a problem with SQLite in Android system (2.3.6) with a motorola defy mini
When I open the database with the open method I coded in a personnal class, i receive the error `sqlite_config failed error code = 21 this should never occur`.

But what I don't understand is that on a HTC Wildfire S, this works fine, and on the emulator too. I don't understand this error.

**InterventionOpenHelper**

```
package com.example.telegestion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class InterventionOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Version de la base de données
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Nom de la Base
    private static final String TELEGESTION_BASE_NAME ="telegestion.db";

    //Nom de la table
    public static final String INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME="Intervention";

    //Descriptions des colonnes
    public static final String COLUMN_IDLIGNE = "idligne";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_IDLIGNE=0;
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_CREATION= "dateCreation";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_DATE_CREATION=1;
    public static final String COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION="heureCreation";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION=2;
    public static final String COLUMN_CODE_ASSO="codeAsso";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_CODE_ASSO=3;    
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_PA="idPA";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_ID_PA=4;
    public static final String COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM= "nomPrenom";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM=5;
    public static final String COLUMN_ACTION_CODE ="actionCode";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_ACTION_CODE=6;
    public static final String COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE ="motifPasCode";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE=7;
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION ="dateIntervention";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION=8;
    public static final String COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION="heureIntervention";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION=9;
    public static final String COLUMN_CODE_PREST="codePrest";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_CODE_PREST=10;
    public static final String COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER="aPositionner";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER=11; 
    public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE="longitude";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_LONGITUDE=12;
    public static final String COLUMN_LATTITUDE="lattitude";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_LATTITUDE=13;
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_GPS="dateGPS";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_DATE_GPS=14;
    public static final String COLUMN_HEURE_GPS="heureGPS";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_GPS=15;
    public static final String COLUMN_KM="km";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_KM=16;
    public static final String COLUMN_ANNULER="annuler";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_ANNULER=17;
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER="dateAnnuler";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER=18;
    public static final String COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER="heureAnnuler";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER=19;
    public static final String COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE="aTransmettre";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE=20;
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS="dateTransmis";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS=21;
    public static final String COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS="heureTransmis";
    public static final int NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS=22;

    public InterventionOpenHelper(Context context, CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, TELEGESTION_BASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        db.execSQL(REQUETE_CREATION_BDD);

    }

    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println("dans le configure");
    }

    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println("dans le open");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Lorsque l'on change le numéro de version de la base on supprime la
        // table puis on la recrée

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME + ";");
            onCreate(db);

    }

    // Requête SQL pour la création da la base
    private static final String REQUETE_CREATION_BDD = 
            "CREATE TABLE "
            + INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME + " (" 
            + COLUMN_IDLIGNE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + COLUMN_DATE_CREATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_CODE_ASSO + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_ID_PA + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_ACTION_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_CODE_PREST + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_LATTITUDE + " REAL NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " REAL NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DATE_GPS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_HEURE_GPS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_KM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_ANNULER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

}
```

**InterventionRepository**

```
package com.example.telegestion;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class InterventionRepository extends Repository<Intervention> {

    public InterventionRepository(Context context) {
        sqLiteOpenHelper = new InterventionOpenHelper(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Intervention> GetAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = maBDD.query(
                InterventionOpenHelper.INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_IDLIGNE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_CREATION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODE_ASSO,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID_PA,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ACTION_CODE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODE_PREST,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_LATTITUDE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_GPS,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_GPS,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_KM,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ANNULER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS }, null,
                null, null, null, null);

        return ConvertCursorToListObject(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public Intervention GetById(int id) {
        Cursor cursor = maBDD.query(
                InterventionOpenHelper.INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_IDLIGNE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_CREATION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODE_ASSO,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID_PA,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ACTION_CODE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODE_PREST,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_LATTITUDE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_GPS,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_GPS,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_KM,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ANNULER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS,
                        InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS },
                InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_IDLIGNE + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);

        return ConvertCursorToObject(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void Save(Intervention entite) {

        DateFormat sfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DateFormat sfHeure = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        String sDateCreation = sfDate.format(entite.getDateCreation());
        String sHeureCreation = sfHeure.format(entite.getHeureCreation());

        String sDateInter = sfDate.format(entite.getDateIntervention());
        String sHeureInter = sfHeure.format(entite.getHeureIntervention());

        String sDateGPS = sfDate.format(entite.getDateGPS());
        String sHeureGPS = sfHeure.format(entite.getHeureGPS());

        String sDateAnnuler = sfDate.format(entite.getDateAnnuler());
        String sHeureAnnuler = sfHeure.format(entite.getHeureAnnuler());

        String sDateTransmis = sfDate.format(entite.getDateTransmis());
        String sHeureTransmis = sfHeure.format(entite.getHeureTransmis());

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_IDLIGNE,
                entite.getIdLigne());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_CREATION,
                sDateCreation);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION,
                sHeureCreation);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODE_ASSO,
                entite.getCodeAsso());
        contentValues
                .put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID_PA, entite.getIdPA());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM,
                entite.getNomPrenom());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ACTION_CODE,
                entite.getActionCode());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE,
                entite.getMotifPasCode());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION,
                sDateInter);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION,
                sHeureInter);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODE_PREST,
                entite.getCodePrest());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER,
                entite.isaPositionner());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_LATTITUDE,
                entite.getLattitude());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE,
                entite.getLongitude());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_GPS, sDateGPS);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_GPS, sHeureGPS);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_KM, entite.getKm());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_ANNULER,
                entite.isAnnuler());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER,
                sDateAnnuler);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER,
                sHeureAnnuler);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE,
                entite.isaTransmettre());
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS,
                sDateTransmis);
        contentValues.put(InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS,
                sHeureTransmis);
        maBDD.insert(InterventionOpenHelper.INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME, null,
                contentValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void Update(Intervention entite) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void Delete(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        maBDD.delete(InterventionOpenHelper.INTERVENTION_TABLE_NAME,
                InterventionOpenHelper.COLUMN_IDLIGNE + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    @Override
    public List<Intervention> ConvertCursorToListObject(Cursor c) {
        List<Intervention> liste = new ArrayList<Intervention>();

        // Si la liste est vide
        if (c.getCount() == 0)
            return liste;

        // position sur le premier item
        c.moveToFirst();

        // Pour chaque item
        do {

            Intervention inter = ConvertCursorToObject(c);

            liste.add(inter);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

        // Fermeture du curseur
        c.close();

        return liste;
    }

    @Override
    public Intervention ConvertCursorToObject(Cursor c) {
        Intervention inter = null;
        try {
            Date cursorDateCrea = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_DATE_CREATION),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date cursorHeureCrea = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_CREATION),
                    "HH:mm:ss");

            Date cursorDateInter = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_DATE_INTERVENTION),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date cursorHeureInter = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_INTERVENTION),
                    "HH:mm:ss");

            Date cursorDateGPS = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_DATE_GPS),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date cursorHeureGPS = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_GPS),
                    "HH:mm:ss");

            Date cursorDateAnnuler = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_DATE_ANNULER),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date cursorHeureAnnuler = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_ANNULER),
                    "HH:mm:ss");

            Date cursorDateTransmis = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_DATE_TRANSMIS),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date cursorHeureTransmis = stringToDate(
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_HEURE_TRANSMIS),
                    "HH:mm:ss");

            inter = new Intervention(
                    c.getInt(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_IDLIGNE),
                    cursorDateCrea,
                    cursorHeureCrea,
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_CODE_ASSO),
                    c.getInt(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_ID_PA),
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_NOM_PRENOM),
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_ACTION_CODE),
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_MOTIF_PAS_CODE),
                    cursorDateInter,
                    cursorHeureInter,
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_CODE_PREST),
                    c.getInt(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_A_POSITIONNER) == 1,
                    c.getDouble(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_LONGITUDE),
                    c.getDouble(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_LATTITUDE),
                    cursorDateGPS,
                    cursorHeureGPS,
                    c.getString(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_KM),
                    c.getInt(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_ANNULER) == 1,
                    cursorDateAnnuler,
                    cursorHeureAnnuler,
                    c.getInt(InterventionOpenHelper.NUM_COLUMN_A_TRANSMETTRE) == 1,
                    cursorDateTransmis, cursorHeureTransmis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return inter;
    }

    @Override
    public Intervention ConvertCursorToOneObject(Cursor c) {
        c.moveToFirst();

        Intervention inter = ConvertCursorToObject(c);

        c.close();
        return inter;
    }

    public static Date stringToDate(String sDate, String sFormat)
            throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(sFormat);
        return sdf.parse(sDate);
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
package com.example.telegestion;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public abstract class Repository<T> implements IRepository<T> {

    // Base de données
    protected SQLiteDatabase maBDD;

    protected SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper;

    public Repository() {

    }

    /**
     * Ouverture de la connection
     */
    public void Open() {

        try {
            maBDD = sqLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fermeture de la connection
     */
    public void Close() {
        maBDD.close();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InterventionOpenHelper ir = new InterventionOpenHelper(this, null);
    ir.Open();
    ir.Close();
}
```

Comment: what is Si quelqu'un pouvait m'aider à ce sujet ce serait sympa?plz use english

Comment: sure ^^
i can translate 
it means : "if someone could help me for this problem, it will be cool "

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not close the connection :-

According to this [documenation](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3.html) for code error =21

and u call db.execSQL repeatedly . i don't know this will solve ur issue or not.

Comment: sorry my code was wrong in the mainActivity, i correct it now
I don't understand what you mean by "you don't close the connection"
Could you explain me what in my code call db.execSQL repeatedly ? cause i make a sysout in the open method of the class InterventionOpenHelper and it appear only once

Comment: ohh.. "db" instance of SQLiteDatabase

Comment: I don't understand your message Sam , could you explain me ?

Comment: Referring to this documentation always close connection. means when u open the database by using instance of SqliteOpenHelper Class then after all operation completed (e.g CRUD ) the database should be closed..

Comment: what i don't understand is that the motorola defy mini is the only android phone which can't create my database
i use a samsung galaxy s wifi 5.0, a htc wildfire s, a samsung galaxy xcover and all of them works fine without any changes in the code